# How can i display count of each column in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNDkN.png)

I would like to count the number of students for each subjects but currently it only displays the number of students for one subject. it only counts the number of student for one subject but i would like to count the number of students in each subject

Added the models.py. Ps still new to django

**views.py**

```
class SubjectView(TemplateView):
    template_name='subjects.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        username=self.request.user.id

        #filter subject taught by lecturer
        classdets=ClassDetail.objects.all().filter(teacher=username).values_list('subject_id')
        print(classdets)

        #filters all subjects from the class details
        subj=Subject.objects.filter(id__in=classdets)
        print(subj)

        #counts number of students
        subjID=Subject.objects.values('id')
        num_student=ClassDetail.objects.filter(id__in=subjID).count
        print(num_student)

        context['subjects'] = subj
        context['no_students'] = num_student

        return context
```

**template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Subjects{% endblock title %}

{% block sidenavbar %}
{% include 'partials/sidenavbar.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
{% include 'partials/navbar.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block subject %}

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card bg-transparent">
      <!-- Card header -->
      <div>
        <div class="card-header bg-transparent border-0">
          <h3 class="mb-0" style="text-transform: uppercase">Current Subjects</h3>
          {% comment %} <a href="{% url 'all-students'%}">View Students</a> {% endcomment %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Translucent table -->
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table align-items-center table-flush" id="datatable-buttons">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th>Subject Name</th>
              <th>Subject Code</th>
              <th>Number of Students</th>
              {% comment %} <th>Generate Attendance Code</th> {% endcomment %}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            {% for subject in subjects %}
                <tbody class="list" style="text-transform: capitalize">
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="row">
                        <div class="media align-items-center">
                         <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                          {% if subject.thumbnail %}
                            <img alt="Logo" src="{{subject.thumbnail.url}}" />
                          {% endif %}
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <span class="name mb-0 text-sm">{{subject}}</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <td class="budget">{{subject.code}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                          <span class="completion mr-2">{{no_students}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {% comment %}
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <span class="completion mr-2">{{attendace_code}}</span>
                        </div>
                        {% endcomment %}
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**models**

```
def get_thumbnail(instance, filename):
    path = f"static/assets/img/custom/{filename}"
    return path

class Subject(models.Model):
    code=models.CharField(max_length=8,unique=True,default="")
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    thumbnail=models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=get_thumbnail)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'code')

class ClassDetail(models.Model):
    teacher=models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    subject=models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default="")
    student=models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,related_name="student")



    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subject}'

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('teacher', 'subject')
```

**userprofile**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    ROLE_LECTURER = 'lecturer'
    ROLE_STUDENT = 'student'
    ROLE_ADMIN = 'admin'

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (ROLE_LECTURER, _('Lecturer')),
        (ROLE_STUDENT, _('Student')),
        (ROLE_ADMIN, _('Admin')),
    )

    STATUS_ACTIVE = 'active'
    STATUS_INACTIVE = 'inactive'
    STATUS_SUSPENDED = 'suspended'
    STATUS_EXPIRED = 'expired'


    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_ACTIVE, _('Active')),
        (STATUS_INACTIVE, _('Inactive')),
        (STATUS_SUSPENDED, _('Suspended')),
        (STATUS_EXPIRED, _("Expired")),

    )

    username = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, verbose_name="Relevant ID")
    status = models.CharField(_('status'), max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=STATUS_ACTIVE)
    role = models.CharField(_('role'), max_length=50, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.username}  ({self.first_name})'

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

Comment: Dear original poster, can you also share your models?

Comment: i updated and added models.py

Comment: @Zainym Can you also share your `UserProfile` model and full template file?

Comment: listen, Edit correctly with `UserProfile` model and also share full template or at least full `<table> </table>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_student =subjID.classdetail_set.all().count()
print(num_student)
```

Comment: it gives an error of AttributeError at /subjects/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'classdetail_set'

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?